# vb.net array.sort() parameters why 1 short?

Tags: vb.net

I'm sorting an array using code like this:

```
Array.Sort(arr, 0, intEndingPosition, New myIComparer)
```

I want the sorting to start with index `0` and end with index `intEndingPosition`. However, the last element `arr(intEndingPosition)` was left out and did not get sorted. Why?

---

`intEndingPosition` is calculated beforehand like this:

```
    Dim StringOfConcern As String
    Dim OneChar(65534), FrqOne(65534) As String
    Dim CntNewOnes, CntRptOnes As Integer

    Dim c As Char
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim isNew As Boolean

        StringOfConcern = TextBox1.Text
        OneChar(0) = CStr(StringOfConcern(0))
        FrqOne(0) = 1
        i = 0
        j = 0 
        For Each c In StringOfConcern.Substring(1)
            isNew = True
            For j = 0 To i Step 1
                If CStr(c) = OneChar(j) Then
                    isNew = False
                    FrqOne(j) += 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            If isNew = True Then
                i += 1
                OneChar(i) = CStr(c)
                FrqOne(i) = 1
            End If
        Next c

    CntNewOnes = i + 1

    CntRptOnes = 0 
    For i = 0 To CntNewOnes - 1 Step 1
        If FrqOne(i) > 1 Then CntRptOnes += 1
    Next i
```

The sorting follows here. The code in my original question is only illustrative. The actual sorting is:

```
    Array.Sort(FrqOne, OneChar, 0, CntNewOnes - 1)
    Array.Reverse(FrqOne, 0, CntNewOnes - 1)
    Array.Reverse(OneChar, 0, CntNewOnes - 1)
```

Comment: ... Where is `intEndingPosition` being set? Where does it's value come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the method declaration for [Array.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Collections_IComparer_)

```
Public Shared Sub Sort (
    array As Array,
    index As Integer,
    length As Integer,
    comparer As IComparer
)
```

The third parameter is *the number of elements in the range to sort* (`length`) not the end index as you suggest.

So let's assume for a minute that your `intEndingPosition` is `4`. This means you're expecting to sort 5 elements i.e. elements at indices `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. However, the number `4` *is* the length and not the end *index* thus you're only sorting elements at indices `0, 1, 2, 3`.

This explains why you're observing that the elements being sorted is one shorter than you expected.

Put it simply the third parameter *should* specify the length of elements to sort and not the end index.

Another Example:

Consider the `Substring` method of the `String` class:

```
Public Function Substring (
    startIndex As Integer,
    length As Integer
) As String
```

Then assume we have this piece of code:

```
Dim temp As String = "testing"
Dim result As String = temp.Substring(0, 4)
```

`result` is now a string containing `4` characters as `4` in the `Substring` call indicates the length that should be retrieved as opposed to the end index.

Had `4` been the end index then you'd expect `result` to contain 5 characters.

Comment: Background: I have a little self-taught experience with vba inside Word. Had never used .net (language) or Studio (environment) before, and as it turned out today, I had never done that again after, either. I raised the above question during a once-in-a-lifetime period of 2 weeks' intensive effort in an attempt to solve a self-assigned (useless) task by learning the relevant programming from scratch. When I logged in again several months later, I forgot what I was talking about and thought some other guy used my account.